# How to maintain the order of the inserts when used uniqueidentifier

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database in SQL-Server with approximately 50 tables, each has as a primary key is a unique identifier. This I did because there are data synchronization and thus avoid conflicts.
The problem comes when I insert new information in a table, I need this to remain in the same order in which it was inserted so that the system can display well when read.
For example, I want to keep

- Ferrari
- BMW
- VW

In that order
When the system reads the information and sample, this is never in that order.
I am sure that SQL accommodates automatically based on some criteria.

Comment: You need to set up an identity column and make it a clustered index.

Comment: or have a date_inserted column with a default value of getdate(), then order by that. There is no implicit order in SQL Server tables.

Comment: When it comes to relational databases you need to be explicit about the order you want to *retrieve* the data in. If you can't formulate the ordering better than "the same order I inserted the data in" you cannot do it. So you need a column with values that can be ordered on, usually something like an identity column or an insertion timestamp. If you don't have any of that, you need to add it.

Comment: But I want to avoid adding new columns as it would be laborious. If there is no other choice, I will do that; I had already contemplated. roryap

Comment: There is no other choice

Comment: rows in database doesnt have order. You need to specify the order with `ORDER BY`

Comment: It's not *as* laborious if you use a text editor to generate the ddl queries.

Comment: Use ORDER BY PK table name in the end of select statement. You wil get the record in order

Comment: @AqeelHaider -- no.  the PK column is a unique identifier.  No order.

Comment: There will be a way to set the order in which data is inserted?

Comment: Because I do not understand, first insert Ferrari and saved either as single record, then insert BMW and remains first, then insert VW and this is in the middle of the two. I do this again and order changes.

Comment: ^ why do you say that?

Comment: because my orderly system needs information from the database because there is a criterion on which to base myself and sort by code

Comment: As i told you use the Order By Statement if you need order for the cars table. In the end of your select statement use Order By car Table, you will get the record in alphabetic order. I don't get your specific problem it's simple.
@roryap why you said no? can you explain it.

Comment: @Aqeel. It is not as simple as it seems, I can not do because the order by the primary key is a unique identifier, so the order changes. I can not alphabetize because that is not the end, is going as inserting information in the system.

Comment: @Richard ignore Aqeel. the simplest way is to create a new column with a default date/time.

Comment: I'll wait if there are no options, I'll do what you tell me. Thank you @Jeremy

Comment: I think you didn't make an identity increment column in your table, that why the problem is coming, you have to alter the table and create one autoincremnt column. This is basic, I'm surprise why on the first place you didn't make that column??

Comment: I just created an identity column and the problem persists. Aqeel, Jeremy

Comment: change your select query to include "ORDER BY newcolumnname"

Comment: Sorry, I got distracted and did not know what I did. Your answer worked, thank you very much Jeremy